# How can I package a Tomcat server into a standalone, double-clickable package?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server

I have a simple Tomcat Server set up in Eclipse on a Windows 7 machine. Eclipse by default uses metadata to deploy Tomcat server instances without having to take over the Tomcat installation folder (and allowing multiple parallel servers, provided they don't try to use the same ports). In order to start my server up, I have to open Eclipse, build my project, and start the server my project is assigned to in the `Servers` view.

I would like to start this same server up:

- Without having to open Eclipse
- With a single action, preferably double-clicking a file on my desktop.
- With its own console window

I've looked into making Java programs into standalones, and the most [common](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm) [suggestion](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html) is to package it into a runnable .jar file. This uses a `Launch configuration`, which doesn't really work for my case because the server has no associated `Launch configuration`; to run it you start a Server rather than clicking `run`.

Is there a built-in way in Eclipse to make the server equivalent of a runnable .jar? That is, is there a built-in way in Eclipse to package a Tomcat server to run as a stand-alone?

Comment: This is a walk in the park with Spring Boot. If you're not using Boot then you simply need to start the server in your main class and package into a uber jar, something like Maven Shade would do the trick.

Comment: Do you specifically need Tomcat or any web container will do? If you aren't tied to Tomcat, [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) is a doddle to integrate.